# Oracle: call to a function fails weirdly

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

If being called under owner account, the following syntax works just fine:

```
SELECT "MY_OWNER"."MY_PACKAGE".Convert(t.Value) FROM My_Table t
```

but when called from under another user I get the following error:

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: ??
```

Where *Column: ??* points to

```
SELECT "MY_OWNER"."MY_PACKAGE".Convert(t.Value) FROM My_Table t
                  ⇑
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE.** It's a **function** that is being called:

```
FUNCTION Convert ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to grant privileges on this package to the other user

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON MY_OWNER.MY_PACKAGE TO the_other_user;
```

You should also check to see whether a_horse_with_no_name is correct. Is this a function that you can call in the way you specify or a procedure which should be called in this way

```
DECLARE
v_value VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
MY_OWNER.MY_PACKAGE.CONVERT(v_value);
END;
```

Also check the package to see what rights are defined.  Current User or package owner.  More details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BABDGGBE)

Comment: @DenisKulagin Don't forget to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I sure did :)